# GetAsyncKeyState(188) does not trigger if ',' is pressed?

Tags: c++, winapi

I try to write a C++ app.
But ' GetAsyncKeyState(188) == -32767'  does not do anything if I press the **,** on my qwerty keyboard.
For some reason GetAsyncKeyState does work for keys that are in the alphabet (like a,b,c, etc)
But not for symbols like ','  or '.'

Comment: Show us how you're calling it.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs the return value from `GetAsyncKeyState()` can have multiple bits set depending on if the key was pressed previously or not, and also can vary if other programs are calling the function at the same time.

If the key is down the return code (which is a signed short) will be negative, so if you just want to test if the key is down the easiest way is:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_OEM_COMMA) < 0) { }
```

Edit: here is some example code that works for me:

```
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("comma is %s\n", GetAsyncKeyState(VK_OEM_COMMA) < 0 ? "down" : "not down");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better is `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_*) & 0x8000`.

Comment: Why is that better? :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter, It's more clear that it's the most significant bit being checked.

Comment: For some reason GetAsyncKeyState does work for keys like a,b,c.... But not like ',' or '.'

Comment: @chris No, I still can't check those symbols.

Comment: Maybe if there was a standard `#define KEYSTATE_DOWN 0x8000` that would make sense but otherwise in terms of code readability I don't think it makes much difference.

Comment: @user88004, I think some of the punctuation has a possibility to vary between keyboards. As I recall, most of the obvious identifiers worked for me.

Comment: @chris GetAsyncKeyState simply doesn't catch the punctuations at all...

Comment: @user88004, I can assure you it does, even if not for every keyboard. I've made a crappy keylogger for myself that caught them just fine (you can instantly tell how crappy it was by it using this function in the first place).

Comment: @chris Do you suggest any other non crappy function that can catch punctuations?

Comment: @user88004, Besides virtual key codes, all I can think of are really only scancodes and other specific things, such as the DirectInput (which is a bad idea for keyboard input) `DIK_*` set. First, try seeing if *any* of the VK_* ones trigger when you press the comma.

Comment: @chris Do you have any **working** code samples?

Comment: I added a working sample to my answer - I just verified that it works fine.

Comment: Yup, works for me as well (though I changed the signature of `main` and included `cstdio`).

Comment: @JonathanPotter It turns out ',' has state '-32768' But I only want to call the function once, not like 10 times...

Comment: If only someone had given you an answer about how to check the state correctly...